# How do i get the addonAfter values to join the value of Input in react antd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input, antd

I have a React Antd `Form.List` where i add x numbers of `<Input>` components.

when i log the values posted from the form, it only returns the input value. I would like to have the `addonAfter` value that is selected for each input to also be included in the value result.

the form code is here:

```
<Form
        name="dynamic_form_nest_item"
        onFinish={onFinish}
        autoComplete="off"
      >
        <Row gutter={16}>
          <Col span={12}>
            <Form.List name="domains">
              {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
                <>
                  {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => {
                    console.log("fields", fields)
                    //console.log(key, name, fields);
                    console.log("fieldName", key);
                    return (
                      <Space
                        key={key}
                        style={{
                          display: "flex",
                          marginBottom: 8,
                        }}
                        align="baseline"
                      >
                        <Form.Item {...restField} name={name}>
                          <Input
                            addonBefore="https://"
                            addonAfter={selectAfter}
                            defaultValue="mysite"
                          />
                        </Form.Item>
                        <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(name)} />
                      </Space>
                    );
                  })}
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Button
                      type="dashed"
                      onClick={() => add()}
                      //block
                      icon={<PlusOutlined />}
                    >
                      Add url
                    </Button>
                  </Form.Item>
                </>
              )}
            </Form.List>
          </Col>
        </Row>

        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
```

and this is the `selectAfter` JSX element if thats needed?

```
 const selectAfter = (
      <Select
        defaultValue=".com"
      >
        <Option value=".com">.com</Option>
        <Option value=".org">.org</Option>
      </Select>
    );
```

If i create two inputs:
[inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBJxT.jpg)

i now get the result: `['test', 'test2']` when i actually want `['test.com', 'test2.org']`

can someone help me in the right direction with this?